# Disable typing cursor on selectize.js

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I have  custom select boxes that I made with selectize.js.

I don't want to let the user have the ability to type. I just want them to select, not search or anything. I don't want the typing cursor to be there anymore.

I've tried

```
persist: false,
readOnly: true,
createOnBlur: true,
create: false,
```

None of those have worked